# Entries with different time validity while preserving foreign key constraints

Tags: sql-server, database, temporal, temporal-database

I have some table where each entry can have different time validity. entry looks like this: (Id, ValidFrom, ValidTo). There can be more such entries with the same Id but with a different validity. (Validity should not overlap). I need to do insert/delete/update operations at current time or any future time point.

All this could be handled in business logic of the application, but I would like to refer to this table from other tables using foreign key.

I found out that [Temporal Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx) could be the way, but there is a small problem. The SysStartTime and SysEndTime columns are determined automatically by the time of INSERT/UPDATE and cannot be set when inserting/updating.

Is there a way how to store a validity information for each entry in database table while allowing foreign key constrains? Is that demand even reasonable?

Comment: A foreign key constraint is difficult to this type of table because of the inequality condition on `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo`.

Answer (score 0):

Temporal tables can give you a solution provided master table of your FK is also temporal table. As to manual management of validFrom and validTo, it is possible (using triggers, for example) but prone to errors. Just some problem to solve:
1. Validity periods should not overlap (already mentioned).
2. Validity periods should not have gaps.

Also be aware that historical data require huge storage volume.